# (see full text) link in chat message reveals reply syntax

Tags: bug, chat, reply

I have a bot that does web searches.  When a user types `>>search something`, the bot responds with a list of 10 results.  A message with that many lines is long enough that it isn't all displayed; instead, there is the `(see full text)` link.  The problem is that the messages starts with `:35584848`, for example, to reply to a previous message.  That syntax is usually special, and it puts that little arrow to the left of the message to signify that this is a reply.  When `(see full text)` is clicked, however, the arrow stays, but the colon and numbers are now displayed.  That makes the message look a little odd.  Can we change that, please?

[image: Screenshot]